# unable to retrieve rows

Tags: python, scrapy

i am using `scrapy 0.14`

bellow is my code

```
start_urls = ['http://lakebagger.com/ur/']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    stores=hxs.select('//table[@id]//tr')
    print len(stores)
```

i am unable to access rows (tr) in **tbody** , rather then that i can only access **thead** row. how can i access the rows ?

thanks in advance . looks like HtmlXpathSelector is unable to rander xpath accurately

Comment: The xpath expression retrieves 484 rows, which is the number of rows in the table. Which data in the table do you want to access?

Comment: are you on windows , at my side its only retrieving 1 row exactly ?

Comment: OSX (10.6.8) running scrapy 0.14.1.

Comment: Providing it's not too long, could you post your settings.py and all of your spider code please? Perhaps something else is causing the issue.

Comment: thanks @Talvalin its all about OS , with same settings its working fine on ubuntu ....

Comment: I'll give it a go on my Windows 7 laptop when I'm back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I would say that it's environmental, albeit not an OS issue, since I managed to get a similar script to work on Windows 7. What are the results of typing "pip freeze"?

Mine:

```
Scrapy==0.16.2
Twisted==12.2.0
distribute==0.6.32
egenix-pyopenssl==0.13.0-1.0.0g-1
lxml==3.0.1
pyOpenSSL==0.9
pywin32==216
w3lib==1.2
zope.interface==3.8.0
```

Also, I really do think you should post your full spider code for examination since there may be something in the missing lines that is causing the issue.

EDIT: Based on your comments, this could be related to versions since you're running 0.14. Have you considered upgrading?

Note: I followed [these steps](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/wiki/How-to-Install-Scrapy-0.14-in-a-64-bit-Windows-7-Environment) to install scrapy.

Comment: i am on scrapy scrapy 0.14, but you are on Scrapy==0.16.2 :) thanks for your efforts ..

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did you resolve the issue? Did you upgrade to Scrapy 0.16.2?

Comment: i don't want to update it to .16 bcoz of many reason ... still on .14